# Allow just that user actived sign_in - Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using `devise` for authentication and have a `activated:boolean` on `users` table.
How can I only allow the activated users to sign in? And show the flash message:

`Login successful` for users activated
and `Login denied` for users `non-activated` / `deactivated` users

Thanks!

Comment: @illusionist Thanks for edit my english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent deactivated users from signing in, override `active_for_authentication?` on your `User` model:

```
def active_for_authentication?
  super && activated
end
```

Comment: Identation is not ok in the answer, but it's quite simple, so I think you'll get it

Comment: A detail, I write in English, but in my system the code is in Portuguese.... so, activated is "ativado" . I can do it: def ativo_for_authentication? My table is Usuario and the column is ativo:boolean

Comment: Amigo, falo português também haha.
Fica da seguinte forma então (se o nome do atributo for "ativo"):

def active_for_authentication?
  super && ativo
end

Comment: O nome do método permanece o mesmo. Você só altera o nome do atributo em "super && nome_do_atributo"

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk, eu ri demais agora ueheuheeu. Eu me passando aqui no ingles. Confesso que ri muito! Tentei ver se vc tinha algum email pra te add nao achei. Sou eltin182 la do grupo rails-br, qualquer coisa se quiser me add no gtalk elton melo santos. Eu vou tentar agora o que vc disse, vlwww cara, vou olhar agora! :D